# If SQL returns no queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have this piece of code:

```
require_once('connectvars2.php'); //This is the connection to my database
                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone ORDER BY id DESC");
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $post = trim($_POST['post']);
                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
                    if (!(empty($data))) { // This is my poor attempt :-)
                    echo 'No result!';
                    }
                }
```

This is my search function on my website.

I want it to return something if there is no queries which match the searchwords. Say if I write "6737" and the database finds no results, it should print "Sorry, but there's no results for your search!".
Is there a way for MySQL to check if there was returned any queries? and if not, echo some text?

Comment: You can simply count the rows, mysql_num_rows but you really shouldn't chuck variables into a query string that's very dangerous, consider looking into PDO.

Comment: [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://php.net/mysql-num-rows). Also [sanitise your inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: How do I make it return no warnings? It's something to do with @ right? I just don't know where to place it

Answer (score 2):

Use mysql_num_rows

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
if(mysql_num_rows($data) > 0){
    //show your data
}
else{
    echo "Sorry, but there are no results for your search!";
}
```

Also, as mentioned, mysql_query is deprecated. Switch to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function to count no. of rows..

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
$num=mysql_num_rows($data);
if($num==0)
{
    echo 'Sorry, but theres no results for your search';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once('connectvars2.php'); //This is the connection to my database
                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone ORDER BY id DESC");
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $post = trim($_POST['post']);
                $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
     if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0){
      echo "Sorry, but there's no results for your search!";
     }else{
     echo "matched";
     }

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
if(mysql_num_rows($data)==0){
    echo "Sorry, but there's no results for your search";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably looking for [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Use like this

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0) {
     echo 'No result!';
}
```

On a side note; you are using the mysql_XX functions to access the database.  These have been replace with Mysqli and MySQL(PDO). Use one of these upto date libraries.

Comment: Hello, I know it's very bad practice and I am currently making a login with prepared statements and mysqli to practice in the correct form. But this is just a fast repair thing for one of my friends. I also wondered, if I like it to print out that theres no row returned, how do I make it stop printing the return failure? It's something to do with @ right? I just can't remember where to place it. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by return failure.  The `@` will ignore any errors generated by a command - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php.  It should be used with caution as suppressing errors without due cause or at the very least logging can become difficult to debug.

Comment: Yeah but it comes with an error because it returns no queries right? So I have to remove that so the user can't see the error, only the message shown when theres found no quieries

Comment: @user2826397 That may be caused by an erroneous query.  The erorr being displayed to user is probably due to misconfigured `php.ini` file - http://superuser.com/questions/527296/how-do-i-disable-all-error-messages-via-php-ini.  Ideally you should check for errors using - `mysql_error()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - function and handle as required.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_num_rows($data)==0

Although you should use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and not mysql as mysql is deprecated nowadays

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**, you should not use `mysql_`-functions cause this PHP extension is deprecated. Try to use `PDO` or `Mysqli` extension instead.

By the way in this extension there is `mysql_num_rows` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) which does exactly what you want.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM calzone WHERE overskrift LIKE '%$post%' OR postnummer = '$post'");
if (!mysql_num_rows($data)) { 
  echo 'No result!';
}
```

Comment: Hello, I know it's very bad practice and I am currently making a login with prepared statements and mysqli to practice in the correct form. But this is just a fast repair thing for one of my friends. I also wondered, if I like it to print out that theres no row returned, how do I make it stop printing the return failure? It's something to do with @ right? I just can't remember where to place it. Thanks

Comment: @user2826397 Yes, @ is the unique error control operator supported by PHP. When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```